# Installing CUDA C++ library?

Tags: c++, gpu

Apologies for sounding a complete n00b, but I have learnt I can call CUDA extension functions to C++ and have the GPU calculate. However, I cant seem to find instructions how to download the library (nor which library I need to download)? Strangely enough I have a great example but I don't know how to get the libraries!

Just so my post is more useful, this is the example I wish to implement:

```
#define N 512
int main(void) {
    int *a, *b, *c; // host copies of a, b, c
    int *d_a, *d_b, *d_c; // device copies of a, b, c
    int size = N * sizeof(int);

    // Alloc space for device copies of a, b, c
    cudaMalloc((void **)&d_a, size);
    cudaMalloc((void **)&d_b, size);
    cudaMalloc((void **)&d_c, size);

    // Alloc space for host copies of a, b, c and setup input values
    a = (int *)malloc(size); random_ints(a, N);
    b = (int *)malloc(size); random_ints(b, N);
    c = (int *)malloc(size);

    // Copy inputs to device
    cudaMemcpy(d_a, a, size, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    cudaMemcpy(d_b, b, size, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

    // Launch add() kernel on GPU with N blocks
    add<<<N,1>>>(d_a, d_b, d_c);

    // Copy result back to host
    cudaMemcpy(c, d_c, size, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);

    // Cleanup
    free(a); free(b); free(c);
    cudaFree(d_a); cudaFree(d_b); cudaFree(d_c);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find Cuda SDK here : [Cuda SDK](https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-downloads)

Wasn't very hard to find to be honest... However, if you are facing this kind of problem in the future, you will usually find the libraries by searching for it's name (here Cuda), followed by "SDK" on Google. Should always be in the first results.

If you want to get started, NVIDIA provides a very nice documentation in my opinion as well as  a section to get started, including an introduction to parallel programming : [Getting Started](https://developer.nvidia.com/get-started-cuda-cc)